# logical error in deletion of an element from a queue implemented as an array

Tags: arrays, c++11

I was making this program for implementing a queue as an array, i am able to successfully insert values into the queue, but when i go for deletion of an element, the following happens : 
 suppose i inserted the following into the queue : 1,2,3
now i wish to delete an element(the whole thing happens according to FIFO mechanism as we all know)

so,
expected output : 2,3

actual output : (blank)

I HAVE AN IMAGE ATTACHED(OF THE OUTPUT SCREEN) AS WELL.

i think that it may be a logical error, i cant figure it out.
I would be glad if anyone of you helped me out.
Thanks!!

THE CODE GOES LIKE : [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ahpak.png)

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;

int Remove(int[]);
int Insert(int[], int);
void Display(int[], int, int);

int front = -1, rear = -1;

void main()
{
    const int size = 50;
    int Q[size];
    int item, res;
    char ch = 'y';
    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        cout << "\n Enter item for insertion : ";
        cin >> item;
        res = Insert(Q, item);
        if (res == -1)
        {
            cout << "\n OVERFLOW!";
            _getch();
        }
        cout << "\n Now the Queue is : ";
        Display(Q, front, rear);
        cout << "\n Do you wish to insert more elemens into the array(y/n)? 
: ";
        cin >> ch;
    }
    cout << "\n Now the deletion of elements from the Queue begins....";
    ch = 'y';
    while (ch == 'y' || ch == 'Y')
    {
        res = Remove(Q);
        if (res == -1)
        {
            cout << "\n UNDERFLOW!";
            _getch();
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "\n The element deleted from the Queue is : " << res << 
endl;
            cout << "\n Now, the Queue(Front--to--Rear) is : ";
            Display(Q, front, rear);
        }
        cout << "\n Do you wish to delete more elements from the Queue(y/n)? 
: ";
        cin >> ch;
    }
    _getch();
    return;
}

int Insert(int Q[], int ele)
{

    const int size = 50;
    if (rear == size - 1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (rear == -1)
        {
            front = rear = 0;
            Q[rear] = ele;
        }
        else
        {
            rear++;
            Q[rear]=ele;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}

int Remove(int Q[])
{
    int ret;
    if (front == -1)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = Q[front];
        if (front = rear)
        {
            front = rear = -1;
        }
        else
        {
            front++;
        }
    }
    return ret;
}

void Display(int Q[], int front, int rear)
{
    if (front == -1)
    {
        return;
    }
    for (int i = front; i < rear; i++)
    {
        cout << Q[i] << " <- ";
    }
    cout << Q[rear] << endl;
}
```

Comment: `if (front = rear)` should be `if (front == rear)`. Read about the difference between comparison `==` and assignment `=` in your favorite C++ textbook

Comment: jeez, thanks a lot Igor, it is again proven that hours of school project work can literally make you forget the difference between assignment and comparison of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mistake is you are assigning rear to front in if condition . if it successfully assign's value then it will execute statement below `if` that means it will set  front and rear as -1.

```
 if (front = rear)
```

it should be like this

```
 if (front == rear)
```

try changing condition in for loop like this

```
 for (int i = front; i <= rear; i++)
    {
        cout << Q[i] << " <- ";
    }
```

Comment: thanks so very much Jasinth, mental fatigue really makes me mess up really obviousthings like assignment and comparison. Thanks a ton for sending that edited piece of code.Cheers!